# How to Make Copy of Scene but change some things

Tags: keyframes, scene, collections

So I am working on a scene with objects, cameras, lights, paths, etc. My goal is to make almost a complete linked scene, however I want to change key frames, minor positional changes, swapping out assets. In prior attempts I made a full copy and that duplicated the entire material list, a linked copy doesn't work because both scenes change, and only settings would just be settings.

Maybe there is a workaround, perhaps saving a version of a scene, and then maybe you could go back to previous versions and change new ones? Perhaps make a scene linked, then unlink specific obj or animations.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making an collection?

A - to select all, shift+D to duplicate, Ctrl+G to create new collection that is NOT Linked to the active scene.

See Blender Guru's Doughnut tutorial Part 5, Level 1 timestamp 2:07
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OTX3ZdYvEA&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&index=6

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/collections/collections.html

---

### Too low rep to post as comment. Hope this helps.